# How to install debian oldstable from network?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

I use PXE debian installer and install it from the local network mirror.

It only offers to install "squeeze - stable" despite of there are both squeeze and lenny on the mirror.

How to force it to install oldstable (lenny)?

When I use legacy network-boot installer, it offers both "oldstable - lenny" and "stable - squeeze", but when I use new one it only offers "stable - squeeze". Can the new installer install old Debian?

Answer (score 0):

The PXE netinstall version of Debian always grabs the latest and greatest "stable" release of Debian (now being Squeeze).  Understandably this is frustrating if you are trying to install Lenny similarly like you are used to since it has been out for a couple of years.  You should go grab one of the old Lenny full dist iso images and go from there.

Comment: How to force it to do it? It there even more "advanced" mode? Can I pass some config option? Where to patch it (when rebuilding it's initrd)?

Comment: There isn't a way to do it.  The only way you can force it is to load the Lenny iso via PXE.  There isn't a way to force the netinstaller to grab an older version because it actually grabs and writes the newest version of the aptitude sources.list.  Your best bet is going to be to do an ISO install vs doing a PXE install.

Answer (score 0):

If 'lenny' is not an option in your PXE boot menue, then you can't force it. 
You could set up a tftp boot server and add the old stable to the boot menue. Read [this wiki](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX) to learn how to set up a tftp boot server. This would give you a choice at install time. You could also add other distros.

Comment: Can't find anything about mirrors or stable/oldstable/lenny/squeeze there. Where to look exactly?

Comment: the approach is a bit different. its independent of debian, you set up a generic netinstall enviroment, and add lenny,squeeze or what ever to it.